# Maintain an order with a OneToMany join

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring boot and want to add a list of products to a page as a foreign key but how can I maintain the ArrayList order when I retrieve from the database? Should I have an intermediate table e.g. `PageProductOrder` which maintains product primary key and order column?

```
@Entity
public class Page {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private List<Product> products;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this by using [`@OrderColumn`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-unidirectional-ordered-list-order-column-example) - this will use a column in the entity for ordering :

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
@OrderColumn(name = "product_index")
private List<Product> products;
```

The column `product_index` in `Product` entity will be used for maintaining order.

Comment: Is it possible to keep this product_index separate from the product table as one product might appear in multiple pages.

Comment: If one product might appear in more pages it should not be one to many but many to many relation. Right now one page can have many products but one product is assigned to one page. Moreover this column will be used by JPA provider only and you do not have a mapping for this column in your entity.

Comment: Ah looking at the docs you linked to, if I remove @JoinColumn I then get the intermediate table I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can define the order by using the `@OrderBy` annotation.

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
@OrderBy(value = "name ASC")
private List<Product> products;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to maintain the order of the list not an already existing field in the database.

Comment: What field / attribute defines the order of the associated products? Just the order of insertions?

Comment: Yes, currently the order they are added to the list. I can have manage pages with the same products so the ordering is specific to one page